# Почему необходимо принудительно ставить совместимость с JRE1.5 при работе с массивами for (int x : m)

Tags: java

Пытаюсь изучить JAVA по видео 2013 года, возникли ошибки при работе с массивами.

ругается на for (int x : m) говорит: нету совместимости с jre1.5 , хотя в настройка стоит 1.4 и выше. Объясните пожалуйста в чем дело.

Comment: Потому что 4 < 5, а синтаксис `for (int x : m)` появился в java 5. Поставьте уровень совместимости jre1.5

Answer (score 1):

Вы обращаетесь к компилятору Java 4, а используете синтаксис из Java 5.

Mеньшая версия Java не умеет работать с большей.